# how i can eliminate the row which equal those if conditions

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia

```
function prealloc()
situation=zeros(Int64,3^5,5);
i=1;
for north=0:2, south=0:2, east=0:2, west=0:2, current=0:2
    situation[i,:]=[north, south, east, west, current]
if situation[i,:]=[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
elseif  situation[i,:]=[2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
elseif situation[i,:]=[2, 2, 2, 2, 0]`enter code here`


end
    i+=1
end
situation
end
```

How can I eliminate the row which equal those if conditions from the array which called situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: the code in your question doesn't run (for several reasons). When posting code in questions, it is good form to put it in a "working example" form, where users can copy and paste it into their editor of choice and it will work without the user having to make educated guesses as to what you are actually trying to do. This is probably one reason the question has received down-votes.

With that out of the way, there are two approaches to accomplish what you are trying to do:

1) Construct your matrix without the indicated rows in the first step. Then you don't need to worry about "deleting the rows" later on. For situations as simple as the one in the question, you could just do something like this:

```
function prealloc()
    x = zeros(Int, 3^5 - 3, 5)
    i = 1
    for n=0:2, s=0:2, ea=0:2, w=0:2, cur=0:2
        if !([n, s, ea, w, cur] == [2, 2, 2, 2, 2] || [n, s, ea, w, cur] == [2, 2, 2, 2, 1] || [n, s, ea, w, cur] == [2, 2, 2, 2, 0])
            x[i, :] = [n, s, ea, w, cur]
            i += 1
        end
    end
    return(x)
end
```

Notice I'm using `Int`, not `Int64`. This will not affect performance, and it means your code will run on both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures.

Another style tip. Don't use semi-colons to end lines. This is a Matlab quirk, and it is not needed in Julia.

2) As other users have suggested, you could construct the entire matrix (including the undesirable rows), and then remove them at a later point. Of course, this necessitates re-allocating the entire matrix, and so is somewhat inefficient (note, you can remove elements of *vectors* in place, i.e. without re-allocation, but not any arrays of dimension 2 or greater). In this case, to encourage code re-use, it makes sense to break the routine down into three separate functions. First, we allocate the entire matrix:

```
function prealloc1()
    x = zeros(Int64,3^5,5)
    i = 1
    for north=0:2, south=0:2, east=0:2, west=0:2, current=0:2
        x[i,:]=[north, south, east, west, current]
        i += 1
    end
    return(x)
end
```

Next, we obtain a vector of indices that we wish to remove. We do this as its own step because we only want to re-allocate the matrix once, rather than re-allocating every time we find a new row we want to delete. For your situation, you could use a function like this:

```
function findCondition(x::Matrix{Int})
    inds = Array(Int, 0)
    for i = 1:size(x, 1)
        if x[i, :] == [2 2 2 2 2]
            push!(inds, i)
        elseif  x[i, :] == [2 2 2 2 1]
            push!(inds, i)
        elseif x[i, :] == [2 2 2 2 0]
            push!(inds, i)
        end
    end
    return(inds)
end
```

Notice that in my comparison statements in this function I use `[2 2 2 2 2]` instead of `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]`. This is because the first construct is a 2-dimensional array (type `Matrix`) while the second is 1-dimensional (type `Vector`). Since `x[i, :]` is of type `Matrix`, the difference is important.

Finally, we need to re-allocate the matrix without the offending rows. As user @Matt B. suggests, this can be done with the following one-liner function:

```
removeIndices(x::Matrix{Int}, inds::Vector{Int}) = x[setdiff(IntSet(1:size(x, 1)), IntSet(inds)), :]
```

Note, applying `setdiff` to `IntSet` here is fast because by construction `inds` will already be sorted in ascending order.

Comment: Using an `IntSet` for the indices and setdiff operation may be just as performant (and way simpler) than your custom `complementSort`.

Comment: Colin T Bowers ,thank you very much......and i will try hard to follow your advice :)

Comment: @MattB. Yep, did a quick speed test, and `IntSet` combined with `setdiff` is faster than my custom algorithm. I've written similar custom algorithms for `union` and `intersect` operations which work for pre-sorted vectors of any type which has a "less-than" function implemented. Is there an approach for this situation already in `Base`? I looked into type `Set` but didn't find much documentation... If the answer is at all lengthy, let me know and I'll turn this into a new SO question. Cheers.

Comment: @TaghreedMohamed No probs, glad to help. You might want to consider switching the answer tick to my answer (or any better answer that might come along), as this will point future viewers of the question in the right direction. The solution of Esteban is not a very good one, as it has the potential to be highly inefficient and may result in bounds violations.

Comment: @ColinTBowers - `Set` does have those operations defined, but it is unsorted, so the optimizations you talk about don't apply.  There's been some talk of adding a `SortedVector` type to Base that would transparently allow for these sorts of optimizations.  Or if `Dict` becomes ordered by default then `Set` would be ordered, too ([#10116](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/10116)).

Comment: As yet another optimization to your answer, you can push the `inds` directly into an IntSet.

Comment: @MattB. That is very interesting. Thanks for the link to the git conversation!

Answer (score -1):

You cannot just delete a row in Julia, the only way to do it, is to create a copy of the array without the row you want to delete. And I think that's not internally implemented and it's intentional.

So you will have to do to it manually, something like this will create a copy of `situation` without the row `i` (which is not the same as saying that it will delete row `i`).

```
situation = vcat(situation[1:i-1,:],situation[i+1:end,:])
```

also, this will actually change the dimensions of `situation` in each iteration, so be careful with that...

Also2, your loop will finish in a bounds error since eventually it will be off limits of your array, maybe you could write something like this to end your loop.

```
if i = length(situation)
    break
else
   i += 1
end
```

Ultimately, you can make a function `delrow` and call it from within your loop:

```
function delrow(array,row)
    return vcat(array[1:row-1,:],array[row+1:end,:])
end
```

then call `situation = delrow(situation,i)`

Comment: The reason row deletion is not supported is because doing it the way you suggest is error-prone (that out of bounds error) and inefficient. Much better to collect a list of row indices to delete, and at the very end remove them all at once: `return situation[setdiff(1:end,idxs_to_delete), :]`

Comment: when i tray to do the function above i got that error "colon has no metho matching colon (::int64,::Array{int64,1})

Comment: @TaghreedMohamed See my answer for a more thorough explanation of what Matt B. is suggesting.